# KnockoutJS: Handle event capture phase

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, event-handling, dom-events

Let's consider the standard way to bind a generic event to a ViewModel method using KnockoutJS:

```
<div data-bind="event: { mousedown: handler }"></div>
```

This code will add `handler` as a listener on the `mousedown` event to the `<div>`. As any other handler, it is attached to the target and bubble phase of the event.

However, I don't see a way of attaching a handler to the [capture phase](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) of an event without resorting to a manual call to `addEventListener` outside of the MVVM pattern provided by Knockout JS.

**Is it possible to bind an handler to the event capture phase using `data-bind` in Knockout JS?**

Comment: create a wrapper function that calls `handler1` and `handler2`, and itself returns true?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @dperry! Perhaps I didn't ask correctly though: I don't want to wrap together `handler1` and `handler2` (I already use a wrapper function for that), I want to declare an event handler that attaches to the capture phase of the event: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: while not the best practice, you could inline it: `data-bind="event: { mousedown: function(){handler1();handler2();return true;} }"`

Comment: I'll update the question to make it clearer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you need to do DOM manipulation that an existing binding handler doesn't do, you write a custom binding handler. Here's a simple demonstration of a capture-phase event handler. You'll have to look at the debugging console to see the output.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.captureEvent = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var arg = valueAccessor();
        for (var eventName in arg) {
            element.addEventListener(eventName, arg[eventName], true);
        }
    }
};

vm = {
    handler: function (event) {
        console.debug(event.currentTarget.id);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
#d1 {
    background-color: red;
    height: 35em;
    width: 35em;
}
#d2 {
    background-color: green;
    height: 25em;
    width: 25em;
}
#d3 {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 15em;
    width: 15em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="d1" data-bind="captureEvent: {mousedown: handler}">
    <div id="d2" data-bind="captureEvent: {mousedown: handler}">
        <div id="d3" data-bind="captureEvent: {mousedown: handler}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Agreed, this is a good pattern - no support in existing bindings, write your own binding.  I have been thinking it would be really cool if we could get a modular repository of third-party bindings.  And people could choose which ones they want included and get a custom download with just those bindings.